# react.js setState call with key but without value?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

Just started to learn react.js and javascript. I'm going through all the documentation on facebook's github, but got stuck with this.

In the *handleCelsiusChange* method of *Calculator* class in [Lifting state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) chapter there is this line:

```
this.setState({scale: 'c', value});
```

So *scale* will get the value 'c'. Okay. But what is this *value* being simply there? Shouldn't it be a key-value pair?
I've checked the [explanation of setState()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html):

> The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to
>   update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object
>   containing keys to update.

But it says nothing relevant about this usage.

*Thanks! :)*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's actually a feature of ES6. If the key matches an existing variable name you can use this shorthand syntax. So instead of writing `value: value` you can simply write `value` as key and variable name are the same.

**Example with ES6**

```
function getCar(make, model, value) {
    return {
        // with property value shorthand
        // syntax, you can omit the property
        // value if key matches variable
        // name
        make,
        model,
        value
    };
}
```

**The equivalent of the above in ES3/ES5**

```
function getCar(make, model, value) {
    return {
        make: make,
        model: model,
        value: value
    };
}
```

*Example taken from [http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/_)*

Comment: What a bad idea...

Answer (score 3):

That is a special shorthand notation from ES6, it means `value: value`, look here https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand for more details